# LDAP groovy-script runs successfully but no changes

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ldap, jenkins-plugins

I am able to run the LDAP groovy script (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29733) successfully but no changes are done to Jenkins config.xml file thus no changes are applied (default is Jenkins database and whoever is logged can do anything).

Is there anything else that needs to happen after the groovy script runs? I'd appreciate if this could be clarified.

I imagine the groovy script would cause changes to the config.xml file as it happens when I configure LDAP via Jenkins Web UI.

Thanks in advance!

```
import hudson.security.*
import jenkins.model.*

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
def hudsonRealm = new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false)
def strategy = new hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy()

String server = 'ldaps://*****:636'
String rootDN = 'DC=*****'
String userSearchBase = 'OU=****'
String userSearch = 'sAMAccountName={0}'
String groupSearchBase = ''
String groupSearchFilter = '(&(objectclass=group)(cn={0}))'
String groupMembershipFilter = '(&(objectCategory=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0}))'
String managerDN = 'CN=*****'
String managerPasswordSecret = '******'
boolean inhibitInferRootDN = false
boolean disableMailAddressResolver = false
String displayNameAttributeName = 'displayname'
String mailAddressAttributeName = 'msExchExtensionCustomAttribute4'

SecurityRealm ldap_realm = new LDAPSecurityRealm(server, rootDN, userSearchBase, userSearch, groupSearchBase, groupSearchFilter, groupMembershipFilter, managerDN, managerPasswordSecret, inhibitInferRootDN, disableMailAddressResolver, null, null, displayNameAttributeName, mailAddressAttributeName)

instance.setSecurityRealm(ldap_realm)
instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(strategy)

{% for account in cj_local_admin_users %}
strategy.add(Jenkins.ADMINISTER, "{{ account }}")
{% endfor %}

instance.save()
```

**UPDATE 1:** From the class doc:

LDAPSecurityRealm(String server, String rootDN, String userSearchBase, String userSearch, String groupSearchBase, String groupSearchFilter, **LDAPGroupMembershipStrategy groupMembershipStrategy**, String managerDN, hudson.util.Secret managerPasswordSecret, boolean inhibitInferRootDN, boolean disableMailAddressResolver, LDAPSecurityRealm.CacheConfiguration cache, LDAPSecurityRealm.EnvironmentProperty[] environmentProperties, String displayNameAttributeName, String mailAddressAttributeName)

Running the script in Jenkins I get "Script1.groovy: 22: unable to resolve class LDAPGroupMembershipStrategy"

**UPDATE 2:**
FromGroupSearchLDAPGroupMembershipStrategy(groupMembershipFilter)

Error: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.FromGroupSearchLDAPGroupMembershipStrategy() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [(&(objectCategory=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0}))]

**UPDATE 3:**
Using groupMembershipFilter works. When running via Jenkins the changes are performed to the config.xml file
When running via Ansible which does the exact same thing it doesn't perform the changes. I have become:yes and become_user:jenkins set

: ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0

Comment: I can confirm the save function does write to the config file, please see https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/jenkins/model/Jenkins.java. In your script it's possible an error is happening before the instance.save(). Can you provide an example of the script?

Comment: Hi Jason. My script runs successfully (no errors) based on issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29733 but there are no changes to the config.xml file which I expect there would be. I updated my question and added the code